# Waterproof power connections

Tags: power, connector, light, waterproof, ip67

I need light up about 960 square feet of translucent flooring from below. It's an outdoor installation, so it needs to be waterproof.

Further, it has to be done in a matter of just a few weeks, and, as usual, at a very low cost.

I'm planning on using LED rope lighting, as it can be waterproof and is easy to install.

But due to the modular nature of the floor I can't just run a lot of sealed cable from the rope lights to the power source(s), I have to have connectors under there that are waterproof as well.

It looks like I'm stuck with expensive twist circular power connectors, and a whole lot of crimping and wiring.

Are there other options? Cheap prewired waterproof extension cords I can cut in half so I only have to perform one connection per line would be nice, but I'm not seeing them.

I need about 10A at 120V through the most heavily loaded connector.

Worst case I was considering silicone heat shrink connections with IEC computer style cables, but that's not much less work and time than real waterproof connector crimping.

What other options might I be missing?

Comment: All installation and hook-up should be done in accordance with all national and local codes.

Comment: Define waterproof - all manner of stuff lives quite happily _outdoors_ without having a very high IP rating. If you design the hardware right then something as simple as commando sockets, commercial Bulgin or Neutrik XLR/speaker multipole connectors often used in outdoors situations (EG lighting & PA at festivals). I assume no-one will be dancing on your floor if the flood waters are lapping round their knees?

Comment: He did define waterproof, in the "ip67" tag, which I believe is NEMA 6

Comment: @JohnU The wiring will be below the floor, water can ingress, and while there is drainage there's a reasonable possibility that when water is puddling enough a connector may be submerged. Ideally no one would be using it when there's water inside, but we're dealing with humans here...

Comment: I just stumbled on this question. It would be interesting to know how you eventually solved your problem. Maybe you could post an answer to your question if you deem it could be interesting.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Ultimately my client took control of that aspect of the project once I explained their options.  They chose not to perform waterproofing at all, but so far as I'm aware the startup failed shortly after for unrelated reasons and it was never used in a wet environment.

Comment: @AdamDavis Thanks anyway. It would have been interesting how such a problem could be solved effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Adafruit carries [these](http://www.adafruit.com/products/744) waterproof 4 conductor cables. I haven't used them and I don't know the manufacturer (post here if you find out, please) but they look like something that could be useful.

Comment: Nice find, sadly they don't support the power requirements, but they'd be fine for data and communications, which is another issue I'm dealing with.  Thanks!